# WebSocket is failed on HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to build a small websocket application. I am trying to implement it on a website that already runs on a secure HTTPS protocol thus the websocket has to be on `wss` to work.

I build the server using the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var key = fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/www.bigriss.com_private_key.key');
var cert = fs.readFileSync( '/etc/apache2/ssl/www.bigriss.com_ssl_certificate.crt' );
var ca = fs.readFileSync( '/etc/apache2/ssl/bigriss.com_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.crt' );

var options = {
  key: key,
  cert: cert,
  ca: ca
};

var https = require('https').createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        var token = socket.handshake.query.token;
    io.emit('chat message', msg + token);
  });
});

https.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Which would seem to me to be a quite simple and standard implementation. I can access the url https://example.com:8080 properly and it is giving the contents that are read at `index.html`. On this html file is where I try to establish a connection using:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://bigriss.com:8080/?token=abc', {
        transports: ['websocket'], 
        upgrade: false,
        secure: true, 
        reconnect: true, 
        rejectUnauthorized : false
});
```

Having played several times with the options. Regardless, I get an error in the Chrome Console as being:

```
failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

In the terminal I get the following node error:

```
nodejs: ../src/util-inl.h:196: TypeName* node::Unwrap(v8::Local<v8::Object>) [with TypeName = node::TLSWrap]: Assertion `(object->InternalFieldCount()) > (0)' failed.
Aborted
```

I have testing this same setup with HTTP and it works correctly. Is there anything in particular that I am missing with HTTPS?

Comment: Does your https server work fine for regular requests (like web page requests)?  You may have to add your CA to your browser so it will be trusted.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, the https works fine even when I load the page in on port 8080 as https...the only thing not working is wss which makes no sense to me